# What is the best way to store sql queries in java

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, dao

I'm writing a simple server using java servlets. For getting data from the database I've written special Dao layer class, and I want to understand where should I store my SQL queries?

```java
@Override
    public boolean checkIsUserExists(String login) {
        try {
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement =
                    connection.prepareStatement("select * from clients where login=?");
            preparedStatement.setString(1, login);
            ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
            if (resultSet.next()) {
                return true;
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return false;
    }
```

Do I need to create a special class `SQLQueries` where I'll store queries as final strings or there any more effective way to do it?

Comment: Side note: you should `close()` your `preparedStatement` and `resultSet`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is a constant, recommend to use a Constants class like this:

```
//cannot be extended
public final class Constants {

   //private constructor
   private Constants(){}
   public static String SQL_FIND_CLIENTS_FOR_LOGIN="select * from clients where login=?;
}
```

Now in your main class do a static import and use it:

```
import static Constants.SQL_FIND_CLIENTS_FOR_LOGIN;
```

Answer (score -1):

It depends on how much time you want to invest.

If it's just some queries and you don't want to create too much overhead, make a java class with final Strings and refer them whenever necessary.
so this line

connection.prepareStatement("select * from clients where login=?");

would become:
connection.prepareStatement(SQLQueries.SELECT_CLIENTS);

As you use Java Servlets (which are heavily outdated) I assume that will be enough :)

If it's more data heavy you can also use liquibase to change structure together with MySQLExpressServer2014 (both are free) or run scripts directly as .sql classes.

Then there is the option to use Spring/Spring Boot, if you really want to get into trouble or know what you're doing.